# Does Faraday's Law take into account the induced flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Picture a conducting loop and a bar magnet. When the bar magnet is brought near the loop, the magnetic flux through the loop changes and induces a current in the loop to resist the change in flux.

The current in the loop is generating a flux in the opposite direction, so therefore the net flux must now be lower, so why does Faraday's law only take into account the external flux?

Comment: What I  think Faraday nor fully explain the whole thing which result of induce emf, there is also case of self induction, which nothing but back emf not explain by the Faraday.